# How to properly format PDO::FETCH_NUM into JSON results

Tags: php, json, pdo

I'm returning a JSON document like this:

```
ug_gpid: [[4], [2], [3]]
```

This is not the intended format, I want this:

```
ug_gpid: [4, 2, 3]
```

This is my code:

```php
$user = json_decode($resp, true);
$sql = "SELECT ug_gpid FROM user_group WHERE ug_usid =:id AND ug_status = 1";

try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($user as $item => $value) {
        $newUser[$item] = $value;
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $value["us_id"]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $ugroup = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        $newUser[$item]['ug_gpid'] = $ugroup;
    }
    $db = null;
    $response = $app->response();
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    echo json_encode($newUser, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);     
} catch(PDOException $e) {                  
    $error = array("queryGroupError"=> array("text"=>$e->getMessage()));
    echo json_encode($error); 
}
```

I store the result in `$ugroup`. How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: Consider returning an HTTP error status code (4xx / 5xx) in the `catch` block. That way, any API client can catch the error better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `PDOStatement::fetchAll` returns an array of arrays. You want to build a flat array of single values.

I'd use this instead...

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $us_id);
foreach ($user as $item => $value) {
    $newUser[$item] = $value;
    $us_id = $value['us_id']; // this is for the bind
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($gpid = $stmt->fetchColumn()) {
        $newUser[$item]['ug_gpid'][] = $gpid;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will only return `[4]` instead of `[4, 2, 3]`

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul Oops, I slightly misunderstood your code. Should be fixed now

Comment: thanks to you @phil. I modified a bit your code. You save my day.. thanks again

Comment: Could be a dv based on prior content version; upvoted.

Comment: @Jack Nope, it came in long after the final edit. I doubt drive-by downvoter is going to come back and comment

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't work as expected is already answered; however, it would be more efficient to use a single query:

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "SELECT ug_usid, GROUP_CONCAT(ug_gpid)
       FROM user_group 
       WHERE ug_usid IN (%s) AND ug_status = 1
       GROUP BY ug_usid",
    str_pad('?', count($user) * 2 - 1, ',?');
);

// ...

// run query and build search result map
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array_column($user, 'us_id'));
$groups = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);

// extend user information with search results
array_walk($user, function(&$u) use ($groups) {
    if (isset($groups[$user['us_id']])) {
        $u['ug_gpid'] = explode(',', $groups[$user['us_id']]);
    } else {
        $u['ug_gpid'] = [];
    }
});

echo json_encode($user, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Note that it assumes you're using MySQL as the database engine, because it uses `GROUP_CONCAT` which is a MySQL extension of SQL.

Comment: thanks @Jack. Yours is slightly longer than phil's did. Unless you're saying yours is perform much better. Thanks again

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul Theoretically, the performance should be better than multiple queries, but only a benchmark will give the final verdict.

Comment: I'd actually like to see a benchmark. I have a feeling the extra processing time involved in the array and string functions might detract from the single query benefits. Prepared statements are optimised to run in a loop after all